# Oracle compare two count() different tables

Tags: oracle, count, compare

I have a problem with a query, see I have two tables, let say:

```
table a:
progid     |    name  |   type
12         |    john  |    b
12         |    anna  |    c
13         |    sara  |    b
13         |    ben   |    c
14         |    alan  |    b
15         |    george|    b

table b:
progid     |    name  |   type
12         |    john  |    b
12         |    anna  |    c
13         |    sara  |    b
14         |    alan  |    b
15         |    george|    b
```

table a gets count

```
progid   | count(*)
12       | 2
13       | 2
14       | 1
15       | 1
```

table b gets

```
progid   | count(*)
12       | 2
**13     | 1**<-this is what I want to find different count
14       | 1
15       | 1
```

What I want is to find which progid in table b aren't in table a by count, (because as you can see the prog id is there but they should be there the same times! So ben is gone but the progid 13 is there)

So I want to get progid where count varies in the tables, I tried:

```
select a.progid from 
(select progid ,count(*) total from tablea group by progid) a,
(select progid ,count(*) total from tableb group by progid) b 
where
a.progid=b.progid and a.total<>b.total;
```

I get b.total invalid identifier

```
if I use a.count(progid)<>b.count(progid)
```

Error says can't use group functions there, any ideas? I'm desperate!

---

ok i've checked your answers and here's the original one

```
select a.beneficiarioid from 
(select beneficiarioid,count(*) total from lmml_ejercicio_2012_3 where programaid=61 group by beneficiarioid order by beneficiarioid) a,
(select beneficiarioid,count(*) total from ejercicio_2012_3 where programaid=61 group by beneficiarioid order by beneficiarioid) where
a.beneficiarioid=b.beneficiarioid and a.total<>b.total;
```

anyway, i'll try your querys and let you know!! thank you very much!!
btw it's Oracle 11g

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Your statement works fine on Oracle XE

Comment: I tried your statement and it run fine for me. Perhaps if you could put the real names of your tables and your real sql statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a subquery to get each count and then join them using a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select coalesce(a.progId, b.progId) progid,
  coalesce(a.atotal, 0) atotal,
  coalesce(b.btotal, 0) btotal
from
(
  select progid, count(*) aTotal
  from tablea
  group by progId
) a
full outer join
(
  select progid, count(*) bTotal
  from tableb
  group by progId
) b
  on a.progid = b.progid
where coalesce(a.atotal, 0) <> coalesce(b.btotal, 0);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99d2a/5). I used a FULL OUTER JOIN in the event you have rows in one table that do not exist in the other table.

Comment: +1: For very large number of unique progid it may be beneficial to rewrite with common table expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your query works fine on my database, I would prefer set operation:

```
(select progid ,count(*) total from tablea group by progid) 
minus
(select progid ,count(*) total from tableb group by progid)
```

Comment: but if there were registers on tableb that didn't have a corresponding progid on tablea, that wouldn't show it. I think the @bluefeet FULL OUTER JOIN would be better in that case.